# How to add the data point in curve between next and previous point when user click by mouse on curve

Tags: c#, bezier, curve

I am looking to create a curve by points and drag that points by a mouse move that is working fine for me.

But I am stuck to find the previous and next point from the path bezier when users click on a path

Please refer to the attached image to understand my Expectation

[image]

Can you please help me to find the resolution for this

What I have tried:

I referred to this example

[https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/769055/BezierCurveInterpolationSample.zip[^]](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/769055/BezierCurveInterpolationSample.zip%5B%5E%5D)

Comment: 1) This is not a well defined situation as the path could cross on itself and the user could click on the crossing point. Which part of the path would be th right one? You need to find all candidates in the mousemove and let the user pick which he actually wants somehow. If your points are on a GraphicsPath this may help: `private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        if (gp.IsOutlineVisible(e.X, e.Y, p))
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        else Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}` to detect when you hit the line..

Comment: I would use a list of possible neighbours, show them like your image does and also select them from the list and let the user pick either from the list or when the right points on the list are selected. But this may never happen. So user may have to selecte the neighbour(s) first..? Tricky!

Comment: Or you could ignore the tricky situation and only __look for the minimum of the sum of distances between  the new point and all possible pairs of points__. Probably good enough for most situations. For a 100% solution a 'selection mode' could be added to the default click mode which would show a listbox to pick the segment..

Comment: Hm, just did a test and found the result of the minimum-distance solution __highly__ unsatisfactory. Two other ideas: !) create a tightly flattended path and check if the target is actually __on__ one of the segments. or 2) measure distances but also the angles, which should be rather close to 180° . The former seems to be the most reliable way..

Comment: OK, the solution with a flattended path seems to work quite well. It assumes that you GP is created from a List<Point> points and uses a helper function to determine if a point is on a line: `bool IsOnLine(PointF p, PointF p1, PointF p2, float linewidth)
{
    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Wheat, linewidth))
    {
        gp.AddLine(p1, p2);
        return gp.IsOutlineVisible(p, pen);
    }
}`

Comment: The main function searches for the previous point in points: `int FindNPs2(Point pt, List<Point> points)
{
    if (points.Count < 2) return -1;
    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        gp.AddCurve(points.ToArray());
        gp.Flatten();
        int ix = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < gp.PathPoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (IsOnLine(pt, gp.PathPoints[i], gp.PathPoints[i+1], 2))
            {
                ix = i;
                break;
            }
        }`...

Comment: ..        `for (int i = ix; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            int fi = points.IndexOf(Point.Round(gp.PathPoints[i]));
            if (fi >= 0) return fi;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}`

Comment: This will give you the index  of the previous point on the right segment, again, ignoring crossings. The new point would then be inserted at index+1.

Comment: On a process note: remember that Stackoverflow is _not_ a general help forum and you are expected [to put some work into writing your question](/help/how-to-ask). If you have code, show that code in [mcve] form in your post, even if you link out to a more elaborate version of it on another site. External links die, and once they do, your question still needs to make sense. You're asking on Stackoverflow not just for yourself, but for all future visitors who rely on the site to have self-contained questions and answers. So: at the very least, please update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the previous and next control points adjacent to some on-curve point, run through your compound curve and:

1. first, find all segments for which your cursor is inside their bounding box (if you're using a sane curve library, that's built in. If not, it's not too hard to [implement manually](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#boundingbox), then
2. compute the [projection distances](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#projections) of your cursor to each segment you found, then
3. throw away any segment with a projection distance greater than whatever your "close enough" threshold is (e.g. if the cursor is >10px away from a curve, you should probably ignore that click instead of treating it as someone trying to click a curve)

If there are any segments left after those steps, whichever segment has the smallest projection distance is the segment with the desired start and end points you're looking for.